# SocketListener doesn't give callbacks

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, multiplayer, nakama

I'm currently building a multiplayer game in Kotlin/Java and I wanted to use the nakama framework for the backend. I was working on the match-joining system when I noticed that I don't get callbacks from the SocketListener interface of the nakama library. I don't know why this happens

The interface of nakama (java):

```
public interface SocketListener {
    /**
    * Called when the client socket disconnects.
    *
    * Throwable t is set if an error caused the disconnect.
    */
    void onDisconnect(final Throwable t);

    /**
    * Called when the client receives an error.
    *
    * @param error The {@code Error} received.
    */
    void onError(final Error error);

    /**
    * Called when a new topic message has been received.
    *
    * @param message The {@code ChannelMessage} received.
    */
    void onChannelMessage(final ChannelMessage message);

    /**
    * Called when a new topic presence update has been received.
    *
    * @param presence The {@code ChannelPresenceEvent} received.
    */
    void onChannelPresence(final ChannelPresenceEvent presence);

    /**
    * Called when a matchmaking has found a match.
    *
    * @param matched The {@code MatchmakerMatched} received.
    */
    void onMatchmakerMatched(final MatchmakerMatched matched);

    /**
    * Called when a new match data is received.
    *
    * @param matchData The {@code MatchData} received.
    */
    void onMatchData(final MatchData matchData);

    /**
    * Called when a new match presence update is received.
    *
    * @param matchPresence The {@code MatchPresenceEvent} received.
    */
    void onMatchPresence(final MatchPresenceEvent matchPresence);

    /**
    * Called when the client receives new notifications.
    *
    * @param notifications The list of {@code Notification} received.
    */
    void onNotifications(final NotificationList notifications);

    /**
    * Called when the client receives status presence updates.
    *
    * @param presence Updated {@code StatusPresenceEvent} presence.
    */
    void onStatusPresence(final StatusPresenceEvent presence);

    /**
    * Called when the client receives stream presence updates.
    *
    * @param presence Updated {@code StreamPresenceEvent} presence.
    */
    void onStreamPresence(final StreamPresenceEvent presence);

    /**
    * Called when the client receives stream data.
    *
    * @param data Stream {@code StreamData} data received.
    */
    void onStreamData(final StreamData data);
}
```

My implementation in Kotlin:

```
class MSocketListener : SocketListener {
    override fun onDisconnect(t: Throwable?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onError(error: Error?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onChannelMessage(message: ChannelMessage?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onChannelPresence(presence: ChannelPresenceEvent?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onMatchmakerMatched(matched: MatchmakerMatched?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onMatchData(matchData: MatchData?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onMatchPresence(matchPresence: MatchPresenceEvent?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onNotifications(notifications: NotificationList?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStatusPresence(presence: StatusPresenceEvent?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStreamPresence(presence: StreamPresenceEvent?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStreamData(data: StreamData?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why I don't get callbacks?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
I've now also tried implementing the interface in a java class.. still no callback

Java Class (basically the same code as the Kotlin class, just in java):

```
public class NakamaTest implements SocketListener {
    @Override
    public void onDisconnect(Throwable t) {
        //code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Error error) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onChannelMessage(ChannelMessage message) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onChannelPresence(ChannelPresenceEvent presence) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onMatchmakerMatched(MatchmakerMatched matched) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onMatchData(MatchData matchData) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onMatchPresence(MatchPresenceEvent matchPresence) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotifications(NotificationList notifications) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusPresence(StatusPresenceEvent presence) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onStreamPresence(StreamPresenceEvent presence) {
        //code

    }

    @Override
    public void onStreamData(StreamData data) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I finally solved it.
I'm posting this here for the rare case anybody will have the same problem.

First of all, I had to use the `AbstractSocketListener` not the `SocketListener`, which are both provided from the Nakama Framework.

Then you have to create a listener variable like this:

```
val listener: SocketListener = object : AbstractSocketListener() {
    override fun onMatchPresence(matchPresence: MatchPresenceEvent?) {
        super.onMatchPresence(matchPresence)
        //code
    }
}
```

I chose the `onMatchPresence` callback as an example, but you can use all callbacks Nakama provides, which are for example listed in the code block of my question above, or in the [documentation for Java](https://heroiclabs.com/docs/nakama/client-libraries/java/). If you are using android studio, you can just start by typing `override fun *name of callback*` and then press `Tab`. Android Studio should automatically create the rest of the function for you.

In the next step, we need our socket. If you haven't created one yet:

```
val client: Client = DefaultClient("defaultkey")
val socket: SocketClient = client.createSocket()
```

For more information about the creation of the client and the socket [check out the getting started section of the docs](https://heroiclabs.com/docs/nakama/client-libraries/java/#getting-started)

After that, our last step is to link our listener to our socket, which can be done as follows:

```
socket.connect(session, listener).get()
```

After that, you should be set to go! You can place the code you want to execute when you get the callback in the section I marked with the comment.